# Unable to choose the Version of Skype to use

Tags: windows-8.1, skype, windows-update, windows-store

I have Skype which is from the Microsoft Store and I haven't download it as a separate software from the site then why is Microsoft Windows update giving me an update for a desktop version 7.0?

[image: The Windows update history showing the installed update for desktop version for Skype v7.0]

Will it impact on the software I use and what about the Skype which is installed from the Microsoft Store? Why is it not giving any updates like this?  Do I need to uninstall the Windows Store version and continue with this version what the update gives me?

Comment: Microsoft Update does not update the desktop version of Skype, its simply does not have that capability.  I don't know what is going on but that isn't happening.

Comment: @Ramhound that's what I doubt before posting here now I got two Skype's on my Lapp. And I know it's hard to believe but it has done the update

Comment: Unless you can provide a picture of Windows Update history showing a listing for the desktop Skype, then what you are describing without a shadow of a doubt is not possible.  Are you just asking what the changes in Skype 7.0 are?  Those changes are listed on the Skype website.

Comment: There you go with request hope it clarifies your doubt

Comment: I guess I was [wrong](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12050/how-can-i-update-skype-for-windows-desktop) but the changelog still exists on the Skype website.  Microsoft decided to discontinue support of earlier versions of Skype.  The desktop version and the Windows Store version of Skype are 100% independent from one another.  You can both or either one installed if you want.

Comment: [Here](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA34509/what-s-new-in-skype-for-windows-desktop) is the changelog for Skype.

Comment: The reason I use the store version is it doesn't have the  didn't  the annoying Skype icon which stayed evey time in the desktop version.

Comment: You only get Skype through Windows Update if its already installed even then its an optional update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason Microsoft pushed [Skype for Windows desktop out as an optional update](http://www.infoworld.com/article/2901898/microsoft-windows/tuesdays-optional-windows-patch-kb-2876229-can-hijack-your-browser.html#tk.rss_all) in March to Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8.1. I'm not sure why you have it installed unless you deliberately selected it. If you were happy with the Store App, you could have just hidden the update.

There is no problem having both installed although trying to run them simultaneously might be problematical.

Store apps are not updated through Windows update. They update themselves in the background through a different process.

Comment: Is there any way to close the icon from the bottom  I can uninstall it but aren't both the apps running by default when you power on the windows ?

Comment: I didn't install it before but decided to as it used to show in the optional updates evry time for a manual window update

Comment: If you want to go back to how you were before, uninstall the Skype update and then when it shows up again after an update check, right click it and hide it. I would think only trying to make a call on both would cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

1. Uninstall everything Skype related that you currently have.
2. go to Ninite.com, and put a tick in the box next to Skype, then click Get Installer.
3. Save that tiny installer file to your PC, then run it. It will install the latest Desktop version of Skype to your PC automatically.
4. The Skype program should automatically check for updates in the future, or if you prefer you can keep that tiny .exe installer file you downloaded from Ninite, and run it yourself on occasion, and if there are Skype updates, it will automatically update your existing Skype to the latest version.

Personally, I would disregard all Windows Store apps unless that is the only option you have to get the program. IMO, they only add confusion when there are multiple versions like that.

Comment: I'm not on Windows, and didn't know about ninite.com. Still, it felt weird to get software like Skype from some unrelated third party website, with the chance to get some malware installed on the fly. But it seems my concerns are not true; two years ago How-To Geek even said [Spread the Word: Ninite is the Only Safe Place to Get Windows Freeware](http://www.howtogeek.com/201354/ninite-is-the-only-safe-place-to-get-windows-freeware/).

Comment: Even if he does this, Windows Update will still update the desktop version, so I am not sure what using an older version accomplishes.  Skype 6.x can't be used.

Comment: @Arjan, you were right to be suspicious. You need to be in today's internet world, but yes, Ninite is one of the last great software repositories for safe downloads. They don't have many apps, but what they do have is 100% clean.  Also, you say you're not on Windows? Your OP is tagged Win 8.1. -- Ramhound, Skype auto-updates can be disabled inside Skype settings. Also not sure where you're getting Skype 6.x from. Ninite will put the latest version on the PC.

Comment: user3046380 I'm not the OP, I was just trying to indicate I've not used that web site (though it looks legit). (@Ramhound see the comment above, in case you were not notified.)

Comment: The author indicated he didn't update Skype desktop but 7 was installed thus it only makes sense as he wants 6.0 otherwise he can just go to skype.com and get the Skype installer.